# Find if there exists a limit in every point in the functions domain. $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2 y}{(x^2 + y)^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence

$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2 y}{(x^2 + y)^2}$

This is my function. The problem is to find it's domain, and then find all the convergence points in it (if that's the correct translation). The domain is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{(x,y):y=-x^2\}$ I guess.

The points of convergence in that domain are the whole $\mathbb{R}$ (though I don't know how exactly to prove that).

Now, the tricky part is to find if there exists a limit for every points in $\mathbb{R}$. For the points in the domain, the limists obviously exist so we need to look at the points in the parabola.

Since $\lim_{(x,y) \to (x, -x^2)}{f(x,y)}=\frac{-x^3}{0}=-\infty$, that means the limit doesn't exist for all the points in the parabola, except for when $x=0$, right? We have to check for that one manually.

So I tried approaching the $(0, 0)$ from all the straight directions with $x = r\cos(\alpha), y=r\sin(\alpha)$.

$\lim_{r \to 0}{\frac{r^3\cos^2(\alpha)sin(\alpha)}{(r^2\cos^2(\alpha)+r\sin(\alpha))^2}}=\frac{0}{\sin^2(\alpha)}$

That's $0$ for every $\alpha\not=k\pi$. So we test the approach from the horizontal directions manually. That's where $x\in\mathbb{R}, y=0$

So again,

$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x^2 0}{(x^2+0)^2}}=0$

Well then. Since it converges to 0 from all directions, we can't conclude that it doesn't have a limit in $(0, 0)$ but we also can't conclude that it does since it might not exists if we approach it from something that's not a straight line. What can I do now?
Also, going through my steps, does everything seem right? Have I maybe jumped to a conclusion somewhere along the way?

Comment: Maybe you got a mistake on computations, namely on the line :"I tried to approach..." there still exist $r$ in the dominator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After trying to reset my approach a couple of times, I've finally figured out that if you just take $y=x^2$, when $x \to 0$, you get $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of $0$. So the limit doesn't exist.